# asp.net-mvc's ROUTE: The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm using asp.net mvc, but can't access my page, got **404** error.

page's url :

**localhost:2334/RawData/EiphoneNews**

view file's location:

**webroot/View/RawData/TNews/Index.cshtml**

my route:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "RawData", // Route name
           "RawData/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "EiphoneNews", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
           new string[] { "News.Controllers.RawData" }
       );
    }




    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

my controller:

```
namespace News.Controllers.RawData
{
    public class EiphoneNewsController : AuthorizedController
    {
        //
        // GET: /EiphoneNews/
        public ActionResult Index(int pagenum = 0, int pagesize = 20, string queryString = null)
        {...}
    }
}
```

Comment: switch the default and RawData MapRoutes. Now it checks the Default first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swap the 2 route definitions:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       "RawData", // Route name
       "RawData/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "EiphoneNews", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
       new string[] { "News.Controllers.RawData" }
   );


    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Comment: thx, the 404 error solved, but it can't find the view file, my view file location is: webroot/View/RawData/TNews/Index.cshtml

Comment: No, your view must be: `~/Views/EiphoneNews/Index.cshtml`

Comment: can't i set some value to let the asp.net-mvc to search  the path?

Comment: You can, but why do you want to violate the standard conventions? You could specify the path when returning the view: `return View("~/View/RawData/TNews/Index.cshtml", someViewModel);`.

Comment: If this view must be used in some controllers, you can place your view in Views\Shared

Comment: got it, if specify the path then it may increase the chance of making mistakes. 谢谢指教

Answer (score 0):

Switch the route registration, the first route to match is taken which is not the `RawData` one. Since the route is determined before the controller is resolved, it doesn't make a difference that the default route leads to a 404 while the `RawData` route would not.

You may want to install the RouteDebugger package (available through nuget) to see what goes on with routes.